# rSpec tests failing, checked everything I can think of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have been through everything I can think of but I can't figure out why the majority of my tests are failing.

All code is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/6232869

UPDATE:

Test causing issues:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:on_ride_photo).in_array([true, false]) }
```

Errors:

> 1) Coaster validations should ensure inclusion of on_ride_photo in
>   [true, false]
>        Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:on_ride_photo).in_array([true, false]) }
>          [true, false] doesn't match array in validation
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:96:in `block (3 levels) in '

Comment: Post the relevant code here, and create a minimal, reproducible failing scenario. Isolate the problem to a smaller subset of your actual code. Do specs like the `height` validation pass if you use a coaster without height?

Comment: That's the problem. I have tried narrowing it down but can't find anything which contributes directly to it. If I pass in a Coaster with no height, all the height validations fail.

Comment: By "narrowing it down" I mean: create a single model w/ a single property that exhibits the incorrect behavior. There's too much code in that gist to look at, it's almost 500 lines.

Comment: So, create a new model, tests, db table and factory for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `before_validation` callback that sets the values.

That won't play nice with how the shoulda matchers work. Matchers set the value to `nil` (or `[]` if it's a collection) before validation is run. Your `before_validation` method undoes that.

Comment: Ok, But why is that causing issues? Surely that just tweaks the values? I need those to give me proper data when importing from a CSV file.

Comment: Of course it tweaks the values--it sets them to something other than the `nil` set by the shoulda matcher, before validation is run, so there cannot be an invalid value in those properties. IMO doing that before validation defeats the purpose of having the validation; do it during your import process.

Comment: Ok, So, Thanks for the advice. I have removed both callbacks and now do those two checks on import of the CSV. The test I am now having trouble I have posted at the bottom of my OP with the associated errors.

Comment: @rctneil I'd suggest opening a new question for that. When you do you'll need to describe which DB you're using, how you defined that column, any other "hidden" functionality.